# How to input multiple types with one controller action MVC5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-helper, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

I'm really new to MVC and I am trying to be clever..

I have one View that displays one question but offers various methods of responding;

```
@using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity
@model Template.Models.Question

@{
   ViewBag.Title = "View question";
   var qtype = Model.QuestionTypeId;
   ViewBag.Number = Model.Id - 7;
   Html.BeginForm("ViewQuestion", "Question", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }); 
}
<div>
<h4>Question #@ViewBag.Number</h4>
<hr />
<h1> @Model.Question1</h1>
</div>
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
<div class="form-group">
@switch (qtype)
    {
    case 1:
    // Textbox
        @Html.TextArea("Answer", new { @class = "form-control", rows = "4", col = "5" });
        break;
    case 2:
    //      Dropdown
    <select class="form-control" id="Answer">
        @foreach (var item in Model.QuestionOptions.OrderBy(o => o.QuestionOptionRanking))
        {
            <option value="@item.QuestionOption1">@item.QuestionOption1</option>

        }
    </select>
break;
case 3:
//     Checkbox
   <div class="checkbox">
    @foreach (var item in Model.QuestionOptions.OrderBy(o=> o.QuestionOptionRanking))
{
        <input type="checkbox" name="Answer" value="@item.QuestionOption1" />  @item.QuestionOption1 <br />
                }
   </div>
   break;

case 4:
//      Radio buttons
foreach (var item in Model.QuestionOptions.OrderBy(o => o.QuestionOptionRanking))
{
<div class="radio">
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Answer" value="@item.QuestionOption1" />
        @item.QuestionOption1
    </label>
</div>
}

break;
}

</div>
<input type="hidden" name="QuestionId" value="@Model.Id" />
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
     <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Answer" />
  </div>
</div>
```

My ViewModel;

```
    public class ResponseViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int QuestionId { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please answer the question before submitting")]
    public string Answer { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Source { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Status { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public System.DateTime DateStamp { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Duplicate { get; set; }
    public virtual Question Questions { get; set; }
    public object SelectedValue { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<QuestionOption> QuestionOptions { get; set; }

}
```

And finally my action;

```
     [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult ViewQuestion([Bind(Include = "QuestionId, Answer")] ResponseViewModel responseViewModel)
        {
        //var optionSelected = responseViewModel.Answer;
        //if (optionSelected == null)
        //{
        //    optionSelected = responseViewModel.Answer.SelectedValue();
        //}
        Response re = new Models.Response();
        re.Answer = responseViewModel.Answer;
        if (re.Answer == null)
        {
            re.Answer = "Work in progress!";
        //    re.Answer = responseViewModel.SelectedValue();
        //    re.Answer = int.Parse(SelectList["Question.QuestionOption1"]);
        }
            re.UserId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
            re.QuestionId = responseViewModel.QuestionId;
            re.Source = "Web";
            re.Status = "New";
            re.DateStamp = System.DateTime.Now;
            db.Responses.Add(re);
            db.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("ViewQuestion");
    }
```

If you examine the view you will notice an "Answer" can be a textbox, checkbox, radio buttons or dropdown. Everything works fine on display, some questions have dropdownlists, others radio button, etc. Its the posting that's got me stumped. If you notice I have not used HTML Helpers, but old fashion HTML as I kept getting errors that the types I've mentioned did not exist in my helpers.

Post works fine if its a text box, but if you look at my controller action you will see a few commented out attempts to also catch the values if it is one of the other controllers..

I thought I was being clever with my cases, but now I can't seem to write any code that will capture the selected, or checked options.

Any advice would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of one possibility off the top of my head. In MVC, you can have more than one form on a page. Instead of wrapping all of your cases in one form, make each case it's own form with it's own submit button, and have an action method for each one.

**EDIT**

Also in looking at your code, you're going to have a problem with the checkboxes because your Answer property is a String and if more than one checkbox is checked you're going to get an array

Comment: This was a great help! Thanks. I ran some tests and the code works fine for Textbox and radiobutton, but I do need to find the code for the dropdown, and as you observed, I get the first answer from the checkbox, but not the rest. If I am only going to have 3 conditions, should I use an if statement in the controller or case? Is there a performance difference?

Comment: @Alex If you only have three conditions, I would just use an if statement. No need for the case with only three possibilities.